# AngularFire not catching error message for signInWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2, angularfire

**Tech stack:**

- Firebase (firebase: "9.6.3",).
- AngularFire (@angular/fire": "^7.6.1").
- Angular v16.
- Npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/fire

Having trouble catching the error message and stopping it appearing as red in the console log. I've written catch in the service but doesn't seem to stop it,

**App Module:**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthenticationService.
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Login Component:**

```
login(): void {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      const { email, password } = this.form.value;
      try {
        this.authenticationService.login(email, password)
          .then(() => {

          })
          .catch(() => {
            console.log('Error caught 1');
          })
      }
      catch {
        console.log('Error caught 2');
      }
    }
  }
```

**Authentication Service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  constructor(private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) { }

login(email: string, password: string): any {
    try {
      return this.angularFireAuth
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(() => this.router.navigate(['basics']))
        .catch((error: any) => {
          console.warn(error);
        });
    }
    catch {
      console.log('Error caught 3');
    }
  }
```

**Error message I want to catch and prevent showing in console:**

[image]

Comment: Having the error message tells the user that the email doesn't exist. Something I don't want to convey and I'd like to hide this message whilst showing my own generic message in the html. Therefore, if I can get this catcher working then this would be possible

Comment: why don't you try to catch error in login component only and not in authentication services?as my understanding login catch is not triggering since catch is already called in authentication service.

Comment: Thanks @DevVyaas but that doesn't work either.

Comment: maybe this can be helpful : 

https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone

Answer (score 0):

The error handling contained in the description of the singInWithEmailAndPassword function works perfectly for me.

````
/**
 * Asynchronously signs in using an email and password.
 *
 * Fails with an error if the email address and password do not match.
 *
 * Note: The user's password is NOT the password used to access the user's email
 * account. The email address serves as a unique identifier for the user, and
 * the password is used to access the user's account in your Firebase project.
 *
 * See also: {@link firebase.auth.Auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword}.
 *
 * <h4>Error Codes</h4>
 * <dl>
 * <dt>auth/invalid-email</dt>
 * <dd>Thrown if the email address is not valid.</dd>
 * <dt>auth/user-disabled</dt>
 * <dd>Thrown if the user corresponding to the given email has been
 *     disabled.</dd>
 * <dt>auth/user-not-found</dt>
 * <dd>Thrown if there is no user corresponding to the given email.</dd>
 * <dt>auth/wrong-password</dt>
 * <dd>Thrown if the password is invalid for the given email, or the account
 *     corresponding to the email does not have a password set.</dd>
 * </dl>
 *
 * @example
 * ```javascript
 * firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
 *     .catch(function(error) {
 *   // Handle Errors here.
 *   var errorCode = error.code;
 *   var errorMessage = error.message;
 *   if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
 *     alert('Wrong password.');
 *   } else {
 *     alert(errorMessage);
 *   }
 *   console.log(error);
 * });
 * ```
 *
 * @param email The users email address.
 * @param password The users password.
 */
signInWithEmailAndPassword(
  email: string,
  password: string
): Promise<firebase.auth.UserCredential>;
````

In your case something like

```
this.angularFireAuth
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(() => this.router.navigate(['basics']))
    .catch((error) => {
        if (errorCode === 'auth/user-not-found') {
            // Your custom Error Handling
        } else {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```